# How to insert contents of JSON file from S3 folder into postgreSQL table using AWS Glue?

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-glue

I have a very basic ETL process that I would like to implement in AWS Glue. I am new to using AWS services and cannot find out how to set up this process. If someone could suggest how this can be done in AWS Glue, that would be much appreciated. Or if AWS Glue is not the best tool to achieve this, then suggestions of which tools are suitable would be welcome.

The basics of my ETL process requirements are:

- Any new files that are uploaded to a specific S3 folder are to be inserted into a specific postgreSQL table.
- The full filename is to be added to the destination table (to allow incremental loads).
- The files are raw JSON and do not need to be parsed within the ETL process.

I imagine I need to set up a trigger on the S3 folder to call a triggered process when when a file is uploaded.

The pseudocode of what I want the triggered process to do is

```
varFilename = <FullFilenameOfTriggeredS3File>
varFileContents = <raw JSON contents of the file>
varPostgresClient = pg.connect(host,db,user,pwd,port)
varSql = 'INSERT INTO destination_table (filename, data) VALUES ($1, $2)'
varValues = [varFilename, varFileContents]
postgresClient.query(varSql, varValues)
```

I have spend several hours in AWS Glue Studio trying to create a visual job to implement this, but there do not seem to be any options for creating a trigger. There also is no for adding the filename to the data flow. And there appears to be no option to connect to my postgreSQL database (there is a postgreSQL Target, but it is labelled "postgreSQL AWS Glue Data Catalog" which is not my database)

Answer (score 0):

In your Glue Job, you can use Python or Scala to write a script that reads JSON files from the S3 folder and loads them into your PostgreSQL table.
Make use of AWS Glue's dynamic data frames to read the JSON files.
Here's an example script in Python:

```
import sys
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

# Create contexts
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)

# Read JSON files from S3
datasource = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "your-database", table_name = "your-table", transformation_ctx = "datasource")

# Write to PostgreSQL
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame = datasource, catalog_connection = "your-postgres-connection", connection_options = {"dbtable": "your-postgres-table"}, transformation_ctx = "datasink")
```

And to trigger an ETL job in AWS Glue when an S3 object is ingested, you can use an S3 event notification to invoke a Lambda function that starts the Glue job

Comment: thanks for the answer. If a Lambda function is needed to start the AWS Glue job, and the Glue job does the connecting and moving, then couldn't the connecting and moving code be in the Lambda function itself? In which case, the AWS Glue job seems to be an unnecessary step.